# How to add active class to a menu when clicked on it sub menu Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to add active class to a menu when I click on its sub-menu. I have menu bootstrap menu below.

```js
// active navigation
const currentLocation = location.href;
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
const menuLength = menuItem.length;

for (let i = 0; i < menuLength; i++) {
  if (menuItem[i].href === currentLocation) {
    menuItem[i].classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
  <li class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
             About
           </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item " href="about.html">About me</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="myportfolio.html">My portfolio</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="demo.html">Demo</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to make a parent menu active even I click on its sub-menu and redirect to any page.
Anyone can help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `click event` using `addEventListener`...

---

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector("#navbarDropdownMenuLink");
const dropdownItem = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-item");

for (let i = 0; i < dropdownItem.length; i++) {
  dropdownItem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    dropdown.classList.add("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
  <li class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
             About
           </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item " href="#">About me</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My portfolio</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Demo</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Some useful resources**

- [.addEventListener() Documetation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [click event Documetation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)

Comment: Than for you respond. This doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @rahweekh168 It is working completely fine, what is your problem can you elaborate!

Comment: @rahweekh168 Did you meant when we click on `My portfolio` or `Contact`, `About` should have the `.active` class?

Comment: @rahweekh168 I have made some necessary changes, check them out...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to activate the menu that contains the link of the location after reload/redirect of the page after a click within the menu. This should do that (the snippet 'fakes' `location`). The comparison of links to the current location is done using the [URL api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

```js
// active navigation
const fakeLocation = new URL("/myportfolio.html", "https://example.com/").pathname;
//    ^ this would be location.pathname in your code

// loop the menu-li's
document.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item')
  .forEach(link => {
      const links = [...link.querySelectorAll("a")];
      //    ^ find all links within the menu

      link.classList.remove("active");
      //              ^remove all 'active'
      links.forEach(lnk => lnk.classList.remove("active"));
      //              ^ remove all 'active' from a.href too

        const shouldBeActive = links.find(lnk =>
          new URL(lnk.href).pathname === fakeLocation);
        // ^ find the href (path) that equals the current path
        //   note: to find the path of lnk we use the URL api

        // if element is found, 'activate' the href and the parent li
        if (shouldBeActive) {
          shouldBeActive.classList.add("active");
          shouldBeActive.closest("li").classList.add("active");
        }
      });
```

```css
.active {
  color: #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF0000;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<base href="https://example.com/">
<ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
  <!-- currently active -->
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         About
       </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item " href="about.html">About me</a><br>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="myportfolio.html">My portfolio</a><br>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a><br>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="demo.html">Demo</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```